# Need to find an R function to filter and select Headlines of texts

Tags: rstudio

I sadly have no experience with R Studio, probably the solution for my problem is easy.
I have a data package including 40.000 entries. The data is about newspaper Articles, their headlines and their content. 
What I try to do is filter the Headlines. I only want to search for Headlines which include one specific word because I make a research of an specific topic 
Does an Package exist witch can make this possible?

I tried "Sentiment Analysis", "text2vex" and Tidyverse.

Comment: Hi @leo please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I imagine that you have a heading column in your data and a content column.

```
Headings     Contents
H1           C1
H2           C2
...
```

you can use the following code to fetch the headings including a certain string:

```
grep('enter_your_string', Data$Headings, value=TRUE)
```